# Не правильно рисуется вертикальная прерывистая линия canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Пытаясь сделать кривую прерывистую линию на js, у меня появилась много проблем, одна из которых - это неправильное отображение вертикальных линий. Иногда они размываются, иногда вообще выглядит как сплошная. Как это решить, помогите пожалуйста) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Линия `[2,1]` так не выглядит. Вы что-то делаете с канвой, растягивая ее в горизонтальном направлении.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.setLineDash([2,1]);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.lineTo(170,20);
ctx.lineTo(170,120);
ctx.lineTo(20,120);
ctx.lineTo(20,20);
ctx.lineTo(170,120);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```